# How to validate a input field and prevent Dialog dismissing

Tags: android, dialog

In my application I extend the `Dialog class` to get user input for each field and now I want to validate them.

```
public abstract class EditDialogHelper extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private String title;
    private String field;
    private String positive;
    private String negative;
    private EditText etField;
    private TextView tvCount;
    private int characterCount;

    public EditDialogHelper(Context context, String title, String field, String positive, String negative, int characterCount) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.field = field;
        this.positive = positive;
        this.negative = negative;
        this.characterCount = characterCount;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_view);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        etField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etField);
        tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInputCount);
        Button btnConfirmationOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPositive);
        Button btnConfirmationCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNegative);

        final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                tvCount.setText(String.valueOf(characterCount - s.length()));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };

        etField.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        tvTitle.setText(title);
        etField.setText(field);
        etField.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(characterCount)});
        btnConfirmationOk.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnConfirmationCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return  etField.getText().toString().trim();
    }



    private boolean validateInputs(String value) {
        boolean valid = false;
        if (value != null && !(value.equals(""))) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            etField.setError("This can't be left empty");
        }
        return valid;
    }


}
```

Once the dialog opens up I want it to be validated once the `btnConfirmationOk` is clicked and if the field is empty, it should be prevented from dismissing the dialog while showing the error.

Where should I use this `validateInputs` method and in which way it should be modified.

Comment: what I understand from your question, for the time being your dialogue is dismissing on clicking on button even if the fields are empty?

Comment: yes. I want to show the error and prevent the dialog from dismissing.

Comment: on clicking "btnConfirmationOk" what code you are executing? Please share that code

Comment: I presume that all dialog ui is described in custom layout. so i posted the answer which should help you a bit maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is quite simple i guess

```
@Override
void onClick(View view) {
      if (view.getId == R.id.btnPositive) {
       boolean valid = validate("my string");
         if(valid) {
           // do stuff
           dissmis();
         }
        } else {
           dissmis();
        }

}
```

But in my oppinion you should set different listeners to your possitive and negative buttons, instead of tracking everything with `EditDialogHelper` class.

this could be done like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {

   @Override
   void onClick(View v) {
   }    

});
```

p.s. I wrote everything from my head so this could contain compilation errors.